# What is the startup command for installing Alpine in docker?

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

```
apk update && apk add docker

docker ps

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

What command do you need to start docker?

Answer (score -1):

You have to first start *docker* service:

```
rc-service docker start
```

See https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_Init_System for more details.

Comment: / # rc-service

/bin/sh: rc-service: not found.

What do I need to install?

Comment: What version of Alpine you are using?

Comment: golang:1.9.2-alpine3.6

Comment: alpine:3.6
rc-service: not found.

Comment: `/ # sapk add openrc



/ # service docker restart


 * WARNING: docker is already starting
/ # docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

Comment: apk add openrc --no-cache

Comment: ```shell
/ # rc-service docker start
 * WARNING: docker is already starting
/ # docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
/ # 
```